# Where are the NFC PC/SC commands documented?

Tags: c, nfc, mifare, ndef

I have an NFC reader attached to my Windows PC, and I've written a C program to use the Windows SCARD API (in C).  This involves executing the following SCARD API methods from winscard.dll:

```
SCardEstablishContext: to initialize a context
SCardListReaders: to enumerate the readers available
SCardGetStatusChange: to check if an NFC tag is present on a reader
SCardConnect: to connect to the NFC tag when it is present
SCardTransmit: to exchange a request/response with the NFC tag
```

The above commands are well-documented in the Microsoft online help.  And my C code that calls the above API methods works great.  When my program calls the SCardTransmit method, I send the following sequence of 5 bytes to the NFC tag:

```
0xFF 0xCA 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

I have no idea what these 5 bytes mean, or how this message was constructed-- I found this byte sequence in a couple of NFC tutorials online with no explanation.  When the SCardTransmit method returns, the receive buffer is populated with 9 bytes:

```
0x04 0x3c 0xf4 0x1d 0x6f 0x61 0x80 0x90 0x00
```

The first 7 bytes are the UID of the NFC tag.  I have no idea what the last two bytes 0x90 0x00 mean.

My question is, where are these low-level NFC commands documented?  I have absolutely no idea how the sequence `0xFF 0xCA 0x00 0x00 0x00` was constructed.  Why does the command start with `0xFF`?  What does `0xCA` mean?  Why are there 3 zero bytes?

The only way I knew to send `0xFF 0xCA 0x00 0x00 0x00` in the request was from reading a couple of NFC tutorials online, and they say that these 5 bytes query the NFC tag's UID.  And it works.  But where is this command documented?  Where are all the other low-level NFC commands documented?

For example, if I want to read a memory block from the NFC tag, what sequence of request bytes would I send with SCardTransmit?  No one seems to talk about these low-level commands that you use to interact with the NFC tag.

Comment: No idea where the actual spec is but you may find this reference useful: https://docs.springcard.com/books/SpringCore/PCSC_Operation/APDU_Interpreter/Standard_instructions/GET_DATA good luck

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card_application_protocol_data_unit links to https://www.iso.org/standard/77180.html . Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30550899/what-is-the-structure-of-an-application-protocol-data-unit-apdu-command-and-re . Should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without details of the reader hardware and the NFC Tag hardware used it is difficult to exactly answer, but here are some pointers.

First is the reader hardware, details can be found in it's datasheet, for example a common usb reader is the [acr122u](https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/) and it's [datasheet](https://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/419/API-ACR122U-2.04.pdf) outlines in section 4.1 that `0xFF` is a "Pseudo-APDU" for sending to non iso 7816 (NFC Type 4) Tags, specifically to `0xCA 0x00 0x00 0x00` is to ask for a Mifare Classic (Non NFC standard) Tag for it's ID.

As you can see it returns the ID plus `90 00h` which is the ADPU "The operation completed successfully." code.

More commands standard commands are available in the reader's datasheet.

You can get more details about the commands that each type of Tag supports from the Tag's datasheet, e.g. The [Mifare Classic](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF1S70YYX_V1.pdf) or [NTAG21X](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf) (NFC Type 2)

Usually a Tag can support more than the minimum command set required by the NFC Type standards links for each NFC Type standard, Type - [1](https://web.archive.org/web/20210125124039*/http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-1-Tag_1.1.pdf), [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20201130205752/http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-2-Tag_1.1.pdf), [3](https://web.archive.org/web/20210125135127*/http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-3-Tag_1.1.pdf), [4](https://web.archive.org/web/20220120125618*/http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-4-Tag_2.0.pdf)

NFC Type 4 tags support [iso 7816-4](https://github.com/dongri/emv-qrcode-doc/blob/master/ISO%20IEC%207816-4.pdf) ADPU's but APDU's are very flexible, there are some industry standard commands but again individual Tags can support additional commands.

Finally to round things of there is the Ndef standard NFC Data format that is used to store data in a standard way on NFC Standard Types of Tags (More details [here](https://github.com/haldean/ndef/tree/master/docs))

Comment: This is helpful, thank you.  My tag is actually not MIFARE, but NTAG215.  In section 10.2 of the NTAG21X spec (that you linked to), it talks about the READ command, which has an command of 0x30.  But this command doesn't work when I send it to the SCardTransmit method.  Furthermore, it mentions a CRC in the command, but no reference to how to compute the CRC.  I feel like the commands in the NTAG21X spec are not meant to be sent with the SCardTransmit method.  Am I missing something?

Comment: NTAG215 is a Mifare Ultralight Tag which is different to the Classic but you should be able to use the "Direct Transmit" Command instead, it's slightly more complicated. The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57969196/2373819 should help it references a slightly different datasheet which has more examples. The CRC is usually automatically calculated by the reader hardware.